# How do you use VBA to Find a cell on another sheet and input data to that found cell from the main sheet

Tags: find

Input and Info Page
[image: Data Sheet]

What I am trying to do is run a code that will take an input box with a Date in it on the "Input and Info Page" and the Employee # in "B7 with Index match to find the corresponding cell on the "Press" page and insert the data in "B8" from the Input page to that found cell

I am completely new at VBA and I have tried several index an match iterations but everything I do errors out, I am looking for any ideas as I am having no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out on my own, simply made two cells where I matched the date to the date row and Emp # to The Emp row and then did this for the macro
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Apsnh.png)

Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
Sheets("Press").Select
Range("A1").Select

```
  ActiveCell.Offset(columnoffset:=Range("W3").Value).Activate
  ActiveCell.Offset(Rowoffset:=Range("W2").Value).Activate
  Sheets("Master").Select
  Range("B13").Select
  Selection.Copy
  Sheets("Press").Select
  Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Sheets("Master").Select
  Range("G4").Select
```

End Sub